# prevent newsletter popup to be showed again on different pages

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm implementing a newsletter popup using bootstrap 4.4 static backdrop modal. I have a problem with it, I've created two functions that are responsable to set a session storage key value to avoid that the popup is showed more than one time after that was closed from the user. 
The problem is that every time I visit another page of the same site the function that is supposed to check if the popup was already closed, will not fire, and the popup will be showed again. How I can fix the code?

```
  var openPopup = function(){
    var popupClosed = sessionStorage.getItem('popupClosed');
// check if the session storage is set or set it to false
    if( popupClosed == null ){
      sessionStorage.setItem( 'popupClosed', false );
    }
// check if the popup was closed otherwise show it
    if( popupClosed !== true ){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#newsletterPopup').modal('show');
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
  openPopup();

  var closePopup = function(){
    $('#newsletterPopup').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e){
// set the session storage to true to prevent that the popup is showed again. 
      sessionStorage.setItem( 'popupClosed', true );
    });
  }
  closePopup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you´re setting your `sessionStorage` like so

```
sessionStorage.setItem("popupClosed", false)
```

you end up having this in your storage:

```
Storage {popupClosed: "false", length: 1}
```

Note, that `"false"` is a `string` here, not a `boolean`.
This is because `sessionStorage.setItem` can only store `strings` as value.

In order to get the correct value you need to retrieve it like so

```
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("popupClosed"))
```

Comment: Ok, so I can use JSON.parse() or check for the string to fix the bug. Thanks for the clarification, I never use sessionStorage and localStorage so I didn't know about this detail.

Comment: Correct! Note that `JSON.parse` is designed for stringified `JSON`s not for single values. It would be better to use it for `JSON`s as it is designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
// check if the popup was closed otherwise show it
    if( popupClosed !== true )
```

to

```
// check if the popup was closed otherwise show it
    if( popupClosed != true
```

)

You can do it this ways:

```
function popupClosed(){
    var popupClosed = sessionStorage.getItem('popupClosed');
// check if the session storage is set or set it to false
    if( popupClosed == null ){
      sessionStorage.setItem( 'popupClosed', false );
      alert('False')
    }
// check if the popup was closed otherwise show it
   if( popupClosed != null ){
      alert('done');
    }
  }
```

or

```
function popupClosed(){
    var popupClosed = sessionStorage.getItem('popupClosed');
// check if the session storage is set or set it to false
    if( popupClosed == null ){
      sessionStorage.setItem( 'popupClosed', false );
      alert('False')
    }
// check if the popup was closed otherwise show it
   else{
      alert('done');
    }
  }
```

example:

https://codepen.io/dichado/pen/vYOBXrr